# Recursively print the sequence: 2, 5, 3, 11, 14,…

Tags: java, recursion, sequence

For homework I have to print the sequence: 2,5,3,11,14... I do not need the solution, but only an explanation how to do this. I have been unable to recognize the pattern. I am starting to think this is unsolvable. Perhaps my professor spelled it wrong.

Comment: In that case, it is better to ask your professor for clarification

Comment: i suppose the next number would be 12. 2,5,3,11,14,12,20 ...so on if im not wrong

Comment: I think that you have misread an "8" as a "3": 2,5,8,11,14.  (I'm pretty sure that your professor hasn't set this as a mathematics puzzle ...)

Comment: @StephenC I did not misread it, because I have pdf java problems.

Comment: There is only one way to be sure.  Ask your professor.

Comment: @StephenC I am waiting for his response.

Answer (score 0):

It's too short of a sequence to give a definitive answer, however if we try:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  System.out.print(i * 3 - 1 + " ");
}
```

it will output following:

```
2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 ...
```

If we assume that after every 2 elements of above we simply have to output the number `3` instead of the calculated value:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    System.out.print("3 ");
  } else {
    System.out.print(i * 3 - 1 + " ");
  }
}
```

will output what looks like your sequence of numbers:

```
2 5 3 11 14 3 20 23 3 29 32 3 38 ...
```